# Foreach statement w/ Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am trying to reposition an element each time a user clicks on an input element.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){                   
    $('input').each(function(index) {
             var p = $(this).attr('id');
             var position = p.position();   

             $this.focus(function(){    

             $('#desired_equity_help').css("left", position.left - 435 );
                 $('#desired_equity_help').css("top", position.top -20 );
             $('#desired_equity_help').toggle();                            
             });

    });
});

</script>
```

'desired_equity_help' is the element that I am trying to toggle and reposition based on the input element clicked. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="desired_equity_help" class="form_tooltip" >
                        <div class="tooltip_inner" >            
                            <strong>Desired Equity</strong>
                            <p>Hello World! This is some dummy text.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <span class="apply_form_label">Desired:</span><input  style="width:110px" type="text" id="desired_equity" name="desired_equity"/><br/>
                    <span class="apply_form_label">Break:</span><input style="width:110px" type="text" /> at: <input type="text" style="width:110px" /><select><option>Independent Users</option></select><br/>

                    <span class="apply_form_label">Last One:</span><textarea rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>
                </div>
```

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you don't have a click event handler so nothing is going to happen when you click your input.

Comment: They are input elements, thus I am using .focus()

Comment: Nothing is firing your `.each()`.

Comment: In additions to Chris's comment, you are setting `p` equal to an elements `id` attribute. An id doesn't have a position so your position variable is probably null or undefined.

Comment: Might be a copy/paste issue but $this.focus should be $(this).focus()

Comment: Also if you are using toggle() then you will get problems if you click on one input (focus fires, toggled from invisible to visible) and then a second input (focus fires, toggled from visible to invisible). You look like you want to explicitly use show() (and presumably somewhere else you use hide()).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Forget the foreach and apply the event straight to the selector like so...

```
$('input').focus(function(){
   var p = $(this);
   var position = p.position();   
   $('#desired_equity_help').css("left", position.left - 435 );
   $('#desired_equity_help').css("top", position.top -20 );
   $('#desired_equity_help').show();                            
});

$('input').blur(function(){
    $('#desired_equity_help').hide();//hide on exit of input
});
```

Note: Using position will require your desired_equity_help element to belong to the same parent as your input elements. if this is not the case consider using [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) instead

Comment: This is the right idea, but I'm not sure the implementation is correct.  I'll come back later when I have more time and delete this comment if it is correct, and +1.

Comment: I think this is the kind of solution I am looking for but it doesn't seem to be working right. I have added the HTML above, perhaps there is an issue with my setup.

Comment: @Thomas: What is the effect you are getting?

Comment: Wait I got it...Ill approve the answer once the timer finishes - thanks!

Comment: @Thomas: OK, let me know what you changed too. Also, this would have been a good question to provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example with

Comment: I just forgot to wrap it in a $(document).ready(function(){  statement

Answer (score 3):

This is probably closer to what you are looking for.  You had an undefined variable and the element should probably be `show`n instead of `toggle`d.

```
$('input').each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var position = $this.position();

    $this.focus(function() {
        $('#desired_equity_help').css({"left": position.left + 150,
                                       "top": position.top}).show();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nEMye/

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhhh, it looks like your doing a lot of stuff there, according to what you want to do you don't need the **each()** or **toggle()** methods there. Here is what I would do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').click(function(e){
        var position = $(this).position();
        $('#desired_equity_help')
        .css({"left" : position.left - 435 , 
            "top" : position.top -20 });    
    });
});
```

By binding the **click** event to the input you are telling it to execute that function every time the input is clicked. If you don't want the click method you can change it to the **focus** method or whichever method is relevant to you. The toggle method is unecessary as well, it is more or less used for **switch** type button, a button you would click once and it goes into one state then after you click it again it goes back to the previous state or something like that.

Hope this helps!